# Gnosis Safe SDK createAddOwnerTx returns Error: Invalid owner address provided but the address is actually an owner

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, gnosis-safe, safe-core

I'm building an app to manage a Safe using the Gnosis Safe SDK. The `deploySafe` method works fine for creating one but if I try to add or remove an owner it returns this error:

```
Error: Invalid owner address provided
at OwnerManager.validateOwnerAddress (ownerManager.ts:17:1)
at OwnerManager.encodeRemoveOwnerData (ownerManager.ts:78:1)
at Safe.createRemoveOwnerTx (Safe.ts:700:1)
```

This is what my React.js code looks like

```
const addOwner = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newOwner = e.target[0].value;
    setOwnerInput('');
    setThresholdInput('');
    try{
        
        const isOwner = await safe.isOwner(newOwner)
        await safe.createAddOwnerTx(newOwner);
        const newOwners = [...owners]
        newOwners.push(newOwner)
        nickNames[newOwner] = ''
        setOwners(newOwners)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        setErrorMessage(error)
    }
}
```

`newOwner` is an address that I've been using for testing purposes. I wanted to make sure that it was actually an owner before firing off the addOwner method. It returns true so why am I getting the invalid owner address error when using this method?

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/jackson-/muray-take-home

Answer (score 0):

Hey Have you solved this one? I ran into the same exact problem. Would love to get some insights on how you solved it. :D